# How do I console.log state with forms in React hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When I submit text in the form, I want to be able to see that text in state via console.log.
I added a console.log to trigger directly after state has been added, but I don't see anything in my console, what am I doing wrong?

What I would like to see: I submit "test1" then I submit "test2", I then want to see in my console "test1, test2" in state.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Field />
      </div>
    );
  }


function Field(){
  const [toDoItem, setToDoItem] = useState('');


  const addToDoItem = (event) => {
    setToDoItem(event.target.value), function(){
      console.log(toDoItem)
    }
  }

  return (
        <form>
            <input type="text" value={toDoItem} onChange={addToDoItem}/>
            <input type="submit" value="Add" />
        </form>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

`useState` doesn't provide callback after setting value. You can use `useEffect` instead.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(toDoItem);
  }, [toDoItem]);
```

**EDIT**

It seems like that you want to get toDoItem value on submit. The problem is that the page is reloaded when form is submitted. You can use `event.prefentDefault()` to stop refreshing on form submission.

```
<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
```

```
  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(toDoItem)
  }
```

Comment: After adding text and clicking "Add" I'm still not seeing anything in the console, just an empty ""
https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-lovelace-b8xod?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I've just checked your sandbox and edited my answer. Also, you can check on the edited sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-shamir-iw13z?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

You can log the change in states using a `useEffect`

I'd suggest making a helper function if you tend to do it often:

```
function useLog(name, property) {
  useEffect(() => console.log(name, property), [name, property]);
}
```

Which you'd use as follows:

```
useLog('toDoItem', toDoItem);
```

I set up an example where the toDoItem is logged as it changes and when you submit, it also logs the change in a todoItems array

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function useLog(name, property) {
  useEffect(() => console.log(name, property), [name, property]);
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Field />
    </div>
  );
}

function Field() {
  const [toDoItem, setToDoItem] = useState('');
  useLog('toDoItem', toDoItem);
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  useLog('todos', todos);
  const changeTodo = (event) => {
    setToDoItem(event.target.value);
  };

  const addTodoItem = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setTodos((prev) => prev.concat(toDoItem));
    setToDoItem('');
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={addTodoItem}>
      <input type="text" value={toDoItem} onChange={changeTodo} />
      <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </form>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this is helpful. However, is there a reason that the following doesn't work? After I hit "add" I don't see anything in my console, just an empty " "
https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-lovelace-b8xod?file=/src/App.js

Comment: forms refresh the page on submit by default, that's why I included `event.preventDefault()` in the form handler. https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-morning-tx38h

Comment: I see, but now the "Add" button is disabled. I was hoping to add "test1" to the input, and upon hitting Add I would see it in the console.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-carson-pgjpo?file=/src/App.js seems more like what you are looking for. You want to do something on submission rather than on the input changing. That's why in my original post, I set up the `todos` array to hold the results of the submission

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Field />
      </div>
    );
  }


function Field(){
  const [toDoItem, setToDoItem] = useStateWithCallback('', toDoItem => {
    console.log(toDoItem);
  });


  const addToDoItem = (event) => {
    setToDoItem(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
        <form>
            <input type="text" value={toDoItem} onChange={addToDoItem}/>
            <input type="submit" value="Add" />
        </form>
  );
}

export default App;
```